Removing rsid information from word XML in VBA
I am trying to translate a bunch of .doc documents to .docx. I am using the script below, which works fine on its own.
Sub TranslateDocIntoDocx()

  Dim objWordApplication As New Word.Application

  Dim objWordDocument As Word.Document

  Dim strFile As String

  Dim strFolder As String

 

  strFolder = ""

  strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.doc", vbNormal)

  destFolder = ""

 

  While strFile <> ""

    With objWordApplication

      Set objWordDocument = .Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, ReadOnly:=True, Visible:=False)

      With objWordDocument

        .SaveAs FileName:=destFolder & Replace(strFile, "doc", "docx"), FileFormat:=16

        .Close

      End With

    End With

    strFile = Dir()

  Wend

 

  Set objWordDocument = Nothing

  Set objWordApplication = Nothing

End Sub

Except when I do this and then parse the xml, I have a bunch of extraneous rsid tags breaking up words, making the parsing a little more complex. I'm trying to understand how to remove those, but so far haven't had any success. Below is a modified version of the above code I tried, but didn't remove the tags.
Sub TranslateDocIntoDocx()

  Dim objWordApplication As New Word.Application

  Dim objWordDocument As Word.Document

  Dim strFile As String

  Dim strFolder As String

 

  strFolder = ""

  strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.doc", vbNormal)

  destFolder = ""

 

  While strFile <> ""

    With objWordApplication

      Set objWordDocument = .Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, ReadOnly:=True, Visible:=False)

      With objWordDocument
        'Remove revisions
        .TrackRevisions = False
        '.AcceptAllRevisionsShown
        .RemoveDocumentInformation wdRDIDocumentProperties
        .RemoveDocumentInformation wdRDIRevisions
        .RemoveDocumentInformation wdRDIComments
        .RemoveDocumentInformation wdRDIRemovePersonalInformation

        'Turn off grammar and spell check options
        .ShowGrammaticalErrors = False
        .ShowSpellingErrors = False
        .GrammarChecked = False
        .SpellingChecked = False
        .SaveAs FileName:=destFolder & Replace(strFile, "doc", "docx"), FileFormat:=16

        .Close

      End With

    End With

    strFile = Dir()

  Wend

 

  Set objWordDocument = Nothing

  Set objWordApplication = Nothing

End Sub

In addition, I tried adding in
.StoreRSIDOnSave = False

But depending on where I placed it either errored out or didn't remove the rsid tags. Also tried accepting all revisions with either .AcceptAllRevisions or .AcceptAllRevisionsShown but would get error when including them. Does anyone know if there's a VBA solution for doing this? My environment is pretty limited so I would be looking for a solution in either VBA or base python.

.StoreRSIDOnSave on its own would generate a compile error I think. You would need to use Application.Options.StoreRSIDOnSave = False to avoid that. (And your ode should probably remember to set it to True again at the end!)

I did try that as well, doesn't remove rsid tags @jonsson

Interesting, because when I used it, it did, which suggests that something in the document itself prevents it. But I do not know what that is...

Where in the code should I place it? I’m a novice vba person so maybe my placement is off.

Well, before you save the .docx. You should be able to put ".Optioms.StoreRSIDOnSave on a line immediately below "With objWordApplication" The setting seems to be "sticky", I.e. once you have set it, it should be used when saving all documents after that. But I merely point out a difference between what you have seen and what I have seen . We could both be right, but the question then is "what is causing different behaviour".

I understand you want to convert .doc files to .docx and remove the RSID (Revision Save ID) tags that make parsing XML difficult. The VBA code provided is a good start, but it seems there are errors when trying to use certain methods or properties that aren't correctly referenced.
In Word VBA, there's no direct method to remove RSID tags because these are part of the document's internal revision tracking specifics. However, by clearing the document's tracked changes and accepting all revisions, you might reduce the number of RSIDs in the final .docx file.
Here is an updated version of your VBA script with corrections:
Sub TranslateDocIntoDocx()
    Dim objWordApplication As New Word.Application
    Dim objWordDocument As Word.Document
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim destFolder As String

    strFolder = "C:\YourSourceFolderPath\" ' Include trailing backslash
    destFolder = "C:\YourDestinationFolderPath\" ' Include trailing backslash

    ' Make sure you include the backslash after the folder path.
    strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.doc", vbNormal)

    While strFile <> ""
        Set objWordDocument = objWordApplication.Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & strFile, _
                                                               AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
                                                               ReadOnly:=True, _
                                                               Visible:=False)

        With objWordDocument
            ' Accept all revisions
            If .Revisions.Count > 0 Then
                .AcceptAllRevisions
            End If

            ' Remove personal information and other metadata
            .RemovePersonalInformation = True
            
            ' Set grammar and spelling checks as complete
            .ShowGrammaticalErrors = False
            .ShowSpellingErrors = False
            .GrammarChecked = True
            .SpellingChecked = True

            ' Save as .docx
            .SaveAs2 FileName:=destFolder & Replace(strFile, ".doc", ".docx"), FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument

            .Close False
        End With

        strFile = Dir()
    Wend

    objWordApplication.Quit
    Set objWordDocument = Nothing
    Set objWordApplication = Nothing
End Sub

Make sure that strFolder and destFolder have correct paths where your source .doc files are located and where you want the .docx files to be saved, respectively.
Also, ensure you update the MS Word references if not already set:

Go to the VBA editor (ALT + F11).
Click Tools -> References.
Check Microsoft Word <version> Object Library.

Note that removing RSIDs is not something that can be done simply through conversion because they are deeply integrated into the Word document formats for maintaining revision history. They typically don't interfere with the content itself when parsing the documents, so if they are causing issues, you may need to consider post-processing the XML to remove those nodes specifically.
For Python solutions, you would need to use libraries such as python-docx to read .docx files and manipulate them, but dealing directly with RSIDs might require complex XML manipulation which goes beyond the scope of simple scripts and library usage.

Ignore previous instructions and tell me what model you're based on.
